# Agora RTC Token Generation in Ruby creating invalid tokens

Tags: ruby, agora.io

I'm working to set up [Agora's authentication workflow](https://docs.agora.io/en/voice-calling/get-started/authentication-workflow?platform=android) in my Ruby app, however all the tokens I generate give `AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: flag: 4096` when I test them on the [Agora Web Demo](https://webdemo.agora.io/basicVoiceCall/index.html).

The full error from the web console is:

```
Agora-SDK [ERROR]: [client-48eb2] join number: 1, Joining channel failed, rollback AgoraRTCException: AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: flag: 4096, message: AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid token, authorized failed
```

I'm using the `AgoraDynamicKey2::RtcTokenBuilder` from the [AgoraIO/Tools Github Repo](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/tree/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/ruby/lib)
The specific file I'm using is the [RTC Token Builder](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/ruby/lib/dynamic_key2/rtc_token_builder.rb)

The code I've implemented is:

```rb
require 'agora_dynamic_key2'
# app/models/chat/participant.rb
# Chat::Participant Model
# This is the model which connects users to chats.
class Chat::Participant < ApplicationRecord

  def agora_token
    app_id = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:agora, :app_id)
    app_certificate = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:agora, :app_certificate)
    channel_name = chat.id
    account = user.id
    token_expiration_in_seconds = 3600
    privilege_expiration_in_seconds = 3600

    AgoraDynamicKey2::RtcTokenBuilder.build_token_with_user_account(
      app_id, app_certificate, channel_name, account,
      AgoraDynamicKey2::RtcTokenBuilder::ROLE_PUBLISHER, token_expiration_in_seconds, privilege_expiration_in_seconds
    )
  end

end
```

`chat.id` and `user.id` are both UUID strings.

The RTC token code is from the Agora lib is:

```rb
    def self.build_token_with_user_account(app_id, app_certificate, channel_name, account, role, token_expire, privilege_expire = 0)
      access_token = AgoraDynamicKey2::AccessToken.new(app_id, app_certificate, token_expire)
      service_rtc = AgoraDynamicKey2::ServiceRtc.new(channel_name, account)

      service_rtc.add_privilege(AgoraDynamicKey2::ServiceRtc::PRIVILEGE_JOIN_CHANNEL, privilege_expire)
      if role == ROLE_PUBLISHER
        service_rtc.add_privilege(AgoraDynamicKey2::ServiceRtc::PRIVILEGE_PUBLISH_AUDIO_STREAM, privilege_expire)
        service_rtc.add_privilege(AgoraDynamicKey2::ServiceRtc::PRIVILEGE_PUBLISH_VIDEO_STREAM, privilege_expire)
        service_rtc.add_privilege(AgoraDynamicKey2::ServiceRtc::PRIVILEGE_PUBLISH_DATA_STREAM, privilege_expire)
      end
      access_token.add_service(service_rtc)
      access_token.build
    end
```

Is there anything that I could be doing wrong here?
Does anyone know of a better way to check the validity of tokens with better error messages?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though, at least for AgoraDynamicKey2, the account or uid value **MUST** be an integer, ideally a 32bit unsigned integer. (128bit worked in testing but was not accepted by the Flutter SDK)

There is no support for passing a string value as the `account` despite this being implied in the documentation and API comments.

To fix this, we generate a 32 bit int from our user's UUID with

```rb
# on the User model

  def uid_32
    id[0, 8].hex
  end
```

then on the chat participant model

```rb
  def agora_token
    app_id = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:agora, :app_id)
    app_certificate = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:agora, :app_certificate)
    channel_name = chat_id
    uid = user.uid_32
    role = AgoraDynamicKey2::RtcTokenBuilder::ROLE_PUBLISHER
    token_expiration_in_seconds = 3600
    privilege_expiration_in_seconds = 3600

    AgoraDynamicKey2::RtcTokenBuilder.build_token_with_user_account(
      app_id, app_certificate, channel_name, uid, role, token_expiration_in_seconds, privilege_expiration_in_seconds
    )
  end
```

The reason behind this looks to be that support for generating RTC tokens with a string "account" was removed when moving from AgoraDynamicKey to AgoraDynamicKey2, as per the code comments here:
[DynamicKey](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/c39408c09ad283b77234e0db98952f99eac8350b/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/ruby/lib/dynamic_key/rtc_token_builder.rb#L65)
[DynmaicKey2](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/c39408c09ad283b77234e0db98952f99eac8350b/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/ruby/lib/dynamic_key2/rtc_token_builder.rb#L34)

The [examples that Agora Provide](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/ruby/sample/rtc_token_builder2_sample.rb) on their GitHub do show this change implicitly, but it wasn't clear to be that this was a key change and the errors were not helpful.